# Can I find a driver or something to make the EarPod buttons work on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ear-phones

I have several pairs of Apple EarPods, and I want to be able to use the buttons with music players and the volume on my PC. Is there a piece of software I can install to my computer to let the buttons work?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't need any drivers, controls are standardized across systems. It's probable that the computer you're trying to use it with doesn't have the four pole mic/control combo you need.

[image]